# How can you implement an anti-cheat in a JS game?

Tags: security, web, three.js, game-engine, anti-cheat

I'm planning to make a web-based game (using three.js and socket.io), and one of my main concerns is protection against cheating.

I know the basics to make a secure game, i.e :

- Never trust the client, client is only for rendering and input capturing
- Put your game logic server-side
- The best anti-cheat is the human

Knowing that, vulnerabilities for which i have no ideas how to be protected are precisely those that concern the client and that the server can't check. For example, as an attacker, i can :

- modify the renderer or shaders to make walls invisible (wallhack)
- modify position of the camera, that is simply in a variable
- inject code that will input for me (aimbot)

In classic games (executables), there are programs that can detects illegals operations. Usually, anti-cheats inspect the assembly and check that no dlls are being injected.

Maybe there is an obfuscator that is specialized in this task (even if it means losing performance) ?

**I haven't done all the research yet** but I hope that some of you have already been confronted with this problem, and can save me a lot of time by orienting my research.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is more of a general discussion rather than an answerable question. ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) off-topic item 5). You'd probably find better answers and worthwhile conversation over on the [Game Dev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37392

Comment: The appropriate flag only gives me 5 other Stack sites, and doesn't include Game Dev. Leaving a comment here in case a moderator needs more info on why the flag wasn't categorized correctly.

Comment: JS doesnt compile to machine code and as far as i know there can not be done inline assembly so best anti-cheat is to store everything on server. JS can "hacked" easilly. You can check on server if player angles are not so "robotic" like on aimbot, or build your own OverWatch system like valve :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do an "anti-cheat" engine, you'll have to do that. You can add anything you want client-side, to facilitate the server-side work, but you must never trust the client. All Logic you have must be at least server-side. You can reproduce it client-side if you want, but no client-side only solution will do it.

After the basics:
If you don't mind wrapping HTTP, then use ExpressJS
take a look at this code for express-blacklist and express-defend:

```
var expressDefend = require('express-defend');
var blacklist = require('express-blacklist');
app.use(blacklist.blockRequests('blacklist.txt'));

app.use(expressDefend.protect({ 
    maxAttempts: 5, 
    dropSuspiciousRequest: true, 
    logFile: 'suspicious.log', 
    onMaxAttemptsReached: function(ipAddress, url){
    blacklist.addAddress(ipAddress);
} 
}));
```

as they aren't registered with socket.io, they will be only affected by the Express route

take a look at this: https://github.com/hrt/AnticheatJS

this is a good software you might want to look into: https://www.tuxbihan.org/software/top-05-anti-cheat-software-to-make-fair-for-gamers/

Hope this helps!